# .Net web-app. Hosted on Appharbor. App not connects to SQL server. Entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, appharbor

So...
I use web app with Entity framework.
Now it hosted on Appharbor.com.

On my machine app works ok(with sql server).
But on Appharbor, it fails with "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server".

In web.config:

```
<connectionString>
    <add name="Books" connectionString=""/>
</connectionString>
```

I assume that appharbor insert automatically needest connection string.
In appharbor conn string alias = "Books".
Context:

```
public class BookContext : DbContext
{
    public BookContext() : base("Books") {}
    dbset..
};
```

Another point is I don't understand, what need to put in entity framework metadata?

**UPD**

I try to put connection string from appharbor to web.config, and here is error:

> Keyword not supported: 'server'.

It looks:

```
<add name="Books" connectionString="Server=...;Database=...;User ID=...;Password=...;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

On all "**...**" is strings from Appharbor.

Comment: Are you using an edmx or code first? If code first, the providerName is wrong

Comment: I use code first. In <entityFramework> <providers> I view SqlClient. I need to use SqlClient instead of EntityClient?

Comment: Yes, as providerName use System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: ok. All works. After I recreate app on appharbor. ErikEJ, thanks you too.

Answer (score 0):

The providerName is wrong, use System.Data.SqlClient